# Tensorflow weightNorm with variable length input

Tags: tensorflow

```
in_dim, out_dim = 10, 7
bias = False
activation = None

layer = tfp.layers.weight_norm.WeightNorm(
               tf.keras.layers.Dense(out_dim, input_shape=(None, in_dim, ),
                                     use_bias = bias, activation = activation),
               input_shape = (None, None, in_dim))
```

I would like to give a input with variable length in the second dimension.
Suppose I run the below code first.

```
input = tf.random.normal(shape = (2, 3, 10))
output = layer(input)
output.shape 
# [2, 3, 7]
```

After running the above code, I give another input to network

```
input2 = tf.random.normal(shape = (2, 4, 10))
output2 = layer(input2)
```

However, it causes error

> Input 0 of layer "weight_norm_3" is incompatible with the layer:
> expected shape=(None, 3, 10), found shape=(2, 4, 10)

I would like to give a variable length of second dimension. How can I do it?

Comment: Your input_shape should be `(None, None, in_dim)` in layer definition?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's my mistake. Error still exists when the input_shape is `(None, None, in_dim)`

Comment: I should have not worked with `(None, None, out_dim)`, so i dont think input_shape is setting the shape of the layer. Can you set with `keras.Input(None,None,in_dim) `?

Comment: I just tried as you said, `input_shape = tf.keras.Input(None, None, in_dim)`, but `TypeError: Cannot iterate over a Tensor with unknown first dimension.` this error came out.